# symfony2 doctrine2 postLoad and single table inheritance

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have an entity structure with [Doctrine 2 Single Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) like this:

```
/**    
*
* @ORM\Table(name="animal")
* @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="animaltype", type="integer")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({1 = "Cat", 2 = "Dog"}) 
*/
class Animal
.
.
.
```

This is the inherited Entity:

```
/**    

* @ORM\Entity  
*/
class Dog extends Animal
```

Now i would like to do something with the object with the [postload Event](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html?highlight=postload#postload):

I get the Dog Object from the LifecycleEventArgs Object but just with the attributes from the Dog Entity, at this moment the Listener doesn't know anything about the inherited Attributes from the Animal Entity. 
What am i doing wrong? Does anybody know?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If this is reproducible with some example code, please post an issue on our tracker at http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/

Answer (score 1):

The attributes are private  in your Animal class. I just did something similar, but you need to use the metadata to get the object attributes in your `postLoad` method.

```
$MetaData = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
```

You can then get all the field names (properly formatted, without "_") with

```
foreach (array_keys($MetaData->reflFields) as $value) {

}
```

In order to use the getters of those fields you can do :

```
//this will become $entity->getSomeFieldValue()  
//it will eval to false if this doesn't exist
if ($entity->{'get' . ucfirst($value)}()) {}
```

Your whole code will look something like:

```
//Your listener class


private $reg;


public function __construct(Registry $reg) {
    $this->reg = $reg;
}

public function postLoad( LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs ){

     $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();

     $em = $this->reg->getManager();

     $MetaData = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity ));
     foreach (array_keys($MetaData->reflFields) as $value) {
         if ($entity->{'get' . ucfirst($value)}()) {
             //here you can get the $entity->someGetter() values
         }
     }
}
```

in your service.yml you would do:

```
arguments: ['@doctrine']
tags:
    - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

Keep in mind that unless you switch your parent class variables to `protected` instead of `private`, there is no real way to read them directly. If you need any clarification, let me know, but this method with the metadata worked fine for me. It also gives you associations